# Two similar tokens, but one is not working

Tags: azure, powershell, .net-core, oauth-2.0, openid

Maybe we have someone who understands tokens well.
I have .Net core web app with Microsoft OpenID authentication and token acquisition to call downstream APIs

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
           .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
           .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

I am getting token from API like this:

```
string[] scopes = { "Service.Development" };
string accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes) ;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
var responseRaw = await client.GetAsync("https://link_to_azure_apim_endpoint");
```

Above is not working, but token received using Powershell just works perfectly

```
Connect-AzAccount -TenantId 9f69edf3-***
(Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl api://my-service -TenantId 9f69edf3-***).Token
```

Both tokens are really similar, here are the differences:
iat,nbf and exp, but its normal.
aio - An internal claim used by Azure AD to record data for token reuse. I guess its normal.
appid, but both ids are added to Authorized client applications to APIs app registration
appidacr, 0 is working and 1 is not
uti - but also guess its normal

What do you guys think I am missing.

Comment: Error messages for "not working" is useful for helping troubleshoot. And per my assumption, you may try to use `api://my-service` instead of `Service.Development` in your code..

Comment: token received either providing api and scope or scope only. Error message: "Access denied or invalid access token"

Comment: `Service.Development` is not a microsoft graph api, so it must be an api permission you generated by yourself, if it's a delegate api permission, then it may look like `api://azure_ad_ap_client_id/Service.Development`, if it's an application api permission, then it should look like `api://azure_ad_ap_client_id/.default`. Since you said you can generate an access token via powershell `-ResourceUrl api://my-service`, I deduce you had a delegate api permission, so the scope should be `string[] scopes = { "api://azure_ad_ap_client_id/Service.Development" };`

Comment: `Both tokens are really similar`,did you check the value of `scp` scope of the tokens?

Comment: Yes my app has API permission to that API scope and yes I've tried full scope name: api/scope. I've used text compare tool and mentioned all differences. I suspect that app is missing some kind of permissions.